# Elastic Beanstalk Worker tier build fails with SQSD error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When building an EB application, and Worker environment using CloudFormation the build hangs for a while. When I'm eventually able to check the logs using the EB console I see:

> ---
>
> ### /var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log
>
> 2020-01-07T09:45:07Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 2.4 (2018-09-06)
>   2020-01-07T09:45:07Z init: Cannot load config file. No such file or directory: "/etc/aws-sqsd.d/default.yaml" (AWS::EB::SQSD::FatalError)

This happened both when using a pre-existing queue, and letting EB create one. Given that there is no documentation on the `sqsd.d/default.yaml` file I assume that EB is supposed to generate it for you.

I cannot see any other errors in the logs, and CloudFormation simply fails with `The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].`.

Any thoughts?